# Why won't cron execute my PHP script correctly?

Tags: php, cron

I've got a PHP script (just a simple script) and I'm trying to get it to run as a cronjob. Every time it executes the PHP script, I receive a mail with the PHP script itself.

How can I resolve this? I've searched on Google a lot but I can't find anything that works.

Comment: Show us your current cron entry.

Comment: When you say with the script itself do you mean just the name of the script or all of the code within the script?

Comment: show us the line that you execute your script with... also have you tried executing with CURL instead of PHP?

Comment: @EM-Creations All the code in my script.

Comment: @Odinn I've tried using multiple commands: #!/usr/local/bin/php, /usr/bin/php using cd to navigate to the script first. But nothing works.

Comment: did u also pass the execute flag to the php script? in linux i usually use "php -e"

Comment: @Odinn Should I? I'm using DirectAdmin to execute the Cronjob?

Comment: @HenkdeVries I think it would still be worth for you to paste the exact Cron entry you use at the moment to execute the PHP script.

Comment: DirectAdmin is a type of cpanel, so he cannot give the excat cron entry. Maybe a screenshot?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your DirectAdmin panel go to 'cronjobs' section, I assume you already configured time interval for your cronjob, so you just need to adjust 'command' option, so try:

**First option:**

```
/usr/bin/php -f /home/your_user/public_html/your_script.php
```

This way you will call php script with php interpreter.

**Second option:**

```
lynx -source http://yourdomain.com/your_script.php
```

This way you will execute text based web browser lynx and open desired url so that php script can be run. Lynx is installed by default on most linux servers.

Also I believe that there is a option in DirecAdmin cronjobs section called 'Prevent email' check that so that you don't receive emails.