# Execute mysql query periodically using script

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm new to php. I want to execute mysql query periodically (say every 5 seconds) using script. Query can be anything (as for now such as getting all data one by one from databse or inserting data to database). How can I do this? I've been through some examples but as I'm new to php, I'm not getting.

Comment: ajax, cron job. How the query result is handled?

Comment: you can create event in mysql database check this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html :)

Comment: @vaibhavmande: is there any other way to execute query except using ajax?

Comment: @thumbernirmal depends on what do you want to do with the query result. Can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using event or cron job created on server

**[Event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)**

using event

```
DELIMITER $$

ALTER EVENT `ev_myevent` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND STARTS '2013-10-23 11:00:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO BEGIN
// your code here
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

using cronjob

check this link
1 [Cronjob execute PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796656/cronjob-execute-php-script)

2 [Managing Cron Jobs with PHP](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update content in your site every 5 seconds and update database then you do it by ajax calling. Other then if you want to update database periodically then use cron.